# Laptop & HDMI & External Monitor

Tags: linux, windows, display, hdmi

I have a Toshiba Satellite L50-A 1CX Laptop. And a Philips 220XW8FB/00 monitor. What I want to do is simple. Just connect my Laptop to the monitor via HDMI cable.

And I used to do this without hassle. Like 3 or 4 months ago I connected my Laptop into my monitor without a single problem. But now I've been literally trying every thing for the last 3 days to make it work with no success.

When I connect my Laptop to the monitor via HDMI nothing happens. It says "no video input" on the monitor screen (and yes I select the HDMI option on the monitor.) Also I tried the "windows + P" shortcut to choose what to do with the external monitor and tried all the options clone the screen etc.

So I think something is wrong with the cable or my Laptop's HDMI input. Then I use the same HDMI cable I used and connect my Laptop to my TV. And suddenly it works. Now I think something is wrong with my Monitor.

So I have a internet TV decoder device. (like a netflix thingy) and I connect that to my monitor with the hdmi cable and boom! It works. I can watch TV on my monitor without any problems. The video the audio everything is perfect. So I start to believe that it is somehow software related.

I've been using Windows 10 at the beginning. Since then I uninstalled my laptops both intel&nvidia video drivers and re-install the most updated versions with no success. Format my PC and clean install Windows 10. Clean install windows 7. And lastly clean install Linux Mint. I am writing this one on Linux Mint. And still no success.

My laptop has both VGA and HDMI inputs so I find a VGA cable and connect my laptop to my monitor with it. And it works without issues (I only tried this on Linux Mint) I can connect my monitor using VGA. But as you know you can't get audio with VGA. And also you get better image quality and refresh rates with HDMI. So I want to use HDMI.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance guys..

Answer (score 0):

Is this your keyboard:

[Screenshot of Toshiba keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZhPfh.jpg)

Then try `FN key + F4`

Comment: Yes that is my keyboard. I tried that but with no success. It does the same job as "windows key + p". It gives options like clone the screen extern the screen etc. None of them does any good.

Comment: Does your Display Settings show the external monitor when it's connected?

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)

Comment: You're right @DavidPostill I need the 50 rep, but it's quite hard to answer some questions without the possibility to ask for extra information through the comments.

Comment: So pick questions you **can** answer until you get 50 rep. That's what everybody else has done. That's only 5 **real** answers with one upvote each